# Certain jQuery Mobile slider elements won't revert to a default state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

So I am developing a PhoneGap application which basically allows a user to take a survey and then records the output.

The first few pages of the survey feature three jQuery Mobile sliders per page. Once they start the survey the sliders are supposed to reflect and initial state: the slider handles are supposed to be in the middle of the slider, with no data-highlighting visible (blue progress bar), and all numerical references to the sliders value should be gone:

[image: slider default]

Then when I use the slider, the data-hihglight (blue progress bar) should appear as well as the numerical references:

[image: slider changed value]

All of this works perfectly but when I go to initiate another survey with the applciation still open, or running in the background, certain elements of the sliders don't reset properly. As you can see below, the slider handles revert to the middle, but the data-highlight does not disappear and the numerical references--at least on the handle alone-- hold the old value. In the picture below the actual value of the slider is set to null at this point-- you can see the input box to the left is blank.

[image: slider reset err]

How do I revert these sliders back to their default appearance?

Thank you!

**Update**
Here is my code pertaining to the state of the sliders.

**CSS**

```
.jquerymobileslidercont {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.jquerymobileslidercont label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-track {
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-handle {
    height: 40px !important;
    width: 40px !important;
    margin-top: -20px !important;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-handle .ui-btn-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.ui-header .ui-title{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-handle .ui-btn-text{

    bottom: 17%;
}
```

**JavaScript** ... I call resetSurveyWidgets upon submitting a survey... this is how I am trying to reset the sliders appearance

```
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){

        $(".jquerymobileslider").on("change", function () {
            $(this).closest(".ui-slider").find("a .ui-btn-text").html($(this).val());
         }).on("keyup", function () {
                        $(this).closest(".ui-slider").find("a .ui-btn-text").html($(this).val());
            });

        $(".ui-slider-input").prop("readonly", true);


        if(!visitedSurvey1a){
            $("#survey1a .jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-handle").css("left", "50%");
        }

        if(!visitedSurvey1b){
            $("#survey1b .jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-handle").css("left", "50%");
        }

        if(!visitedSurvey1c){
            $("#survey1c .jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-handle").css("left", "50%");
        }
        ...

function resetSurveyWidgets(){
        console.log("Within resetSurveyWidgets()");

        visitedSurvey1a = false;
        visitedSurvey1b = false;
        visitedSurvey1c = false;

        $(".jquerymobileslider").val(null);//.slider("refresh");
        $(".jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-handle").css("left", "50%");
        ...
```

**HTML of slider elements**

```
<h3>Think about how you feel right now:</h3>\
    <h2>Right now, I feel:</h2>\
    <div class="jqmslidercontsurvey1a">\
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-happy" class="sliderlabel">Happy:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-happy" id="slider-happy" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
        \
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-relax" class="sliderlabel">Relaxed:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-relax" id="slider-relax" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
        \
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-cheer" class="sliderlabel">Cheerful:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-cheer" id="slider-cheer" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
    </div>

<h3>Think about how you feel right now:</h3>\
    <h2>Right now, I feel:</h2>\
    <div class="jqmslidercontsurvey1b">\
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-sad" class="sliderlabel">Sad:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-sad" id="slider-sad" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
    \
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-stress" class="sliderlabel">Stressed:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-stress" id="slider-stress" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
    \
         <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="jquerymobileslidercont">\
            <label for="slider-angry" class="sliderlabel">Angry:</label>\
            <input type="range" name="slider-angry" id="slider-angry" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" class="jquerymobileslider" data-highlight="true" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true">\
        </div>\
    </div>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your resetSurveyWidgets() function, try:

```
$(".jquerymobileslider").val(null).slider("refresh").val(null).change();
$(".jquerymobileslidercont .ui-slider-handle").css("left", "50%");
```

The chained function works like this:

1. `.val(null)` resets the input value to null
2. `.slider('refresh')` gets rid of the blue highlight but then sets
   the value to 0 (initial condition)
3. `.val(null)` resets the value to null once again
4. `.change()` forces the change event code to run which resets the
   handle text to nothing.

This allows you to it with the one jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
  $(".jquerymobileslider").val(null);
        $(".ui-slider-pop").html("");
    $(".ui-slider-handle").html("");
    $(".ui-slider-bg").css("width","0%");
```

Here is the fiddle that goes with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/r74kt/

Comment: If I do that, the blue progress bar will still be apparent and the input box and handle will both reflect 5 instead of being blank. What I am trying to do is have the sliders revert to their original appearance in the first picture above.